# How do I print the a list of arrays from multiple text input using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Code description:

Clicking the button (id=a1) will add text input brackets (e.g. 3 clicks will give 3 text input). I am trying to get the values from all the text inputs and show it on the page,however, my code only prints out the value from the first text input. How can I get it to print all the values from all the text inputs?

```js
// add textbox function onclick
var a1 = 0;
var x = [];

function addInput() {
  document.getElementById('text').innerHTML += "Load magnitude <input type='text' id='a1' value=''/><br />";

  a1 += 1;
}

//Adds inout into list var x
function pushData()

{
  //get value from input text
  var inputText = document.getElementById('a1').value;


  //append data to the array
  x.push(inputText);
  var pval = x;
  document.getElementById('pText').innerHTML = pval;
}
```

```html
<!--Loadtype selection-->
<div class="test">
  Load type:<br>
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a0/Circle_-_black_simple.svg" width="50 height=" 50 alt="unfinished bingo card" onclick="addInput()" />
  <br><br>
</div>

<p id="text"></p>
<button onclick="pushData();">Submit</button>
<p id="pText">List from input inserted here!</p>
<p id="pText2">value of a1</p>
```

Comment: You need to change your input id bacause you are creating N input with the same id a1. So you print always the first value.

Comment: @Fabio_MO, I did the "a1 + = 1" so that the input name changes, am I doing it wrong?

Comment: I added a couple more duplicates. Please use the search and google

Comment: The core issue is a duplicate..correct. You just need to make the `id` of the generated inputs dynamic and probably store them in an array. Then later read from each of those inputs accordingly.

Comment: I’ve reopened it, please post the answer here @NisargShah

Comment: @Nisarg Shah, thanks so much!!

Answer (score 0):

I have made a couple of improvements to your code, that you can see in the code snippet below.

The essential changes you need to make would be,

- Use a class selector instead of ID selector. When you invoke `document.getElementById` it returns one element having the provided ID. Instead you want all the textboxes that were dynamically created. So you can add a CSS class to the input at the time of creation (`class='magnitude-input'`) and afterwards use it to get all inputs (`document.getElementsByClassName('magnitude-input')`).
- Once you get a list of inputs, you can iterate over them and collect their values into an array (`x` in your case). Note that `x` should be definied within the function `pushData`, otherwise it will retain values previously added to it.
- Also, the variable `a1` seems unnecessary after that. So you can remove it.

```js
// add textbox function onclick
function addInput() {
  document.getElementById('text').innerHTML += "Load magnitude <input type='text' class='magnitude-input' value=''/><br />";
}

//Adds inout into list var x
function pushData() {
  var x = [];
  
  //get value from input text
  var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('magnitude-input');
  
  for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    var inputText = inputs[i].value;
  
    //append data to the array
    x.push(inputText);  
  }
  
  document.getElementById('pText').innerHTML = x;
}
```

```html
<!--Loadtype selection-->
<div class="test">
  Load type:<br>
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a0/Circle_-_black_simple.svg" width="50 height=" 50 alt="unfinished bingo card" onclick="addInput()" />
  <br><br>
</div>

<p id="text"></p>
<button onclick="pushData();">Submit</button>
<p id="pText">List from input inserted here!</p>
<p id="pText2">value of a1</p>
```